# How to add System.Now() with Seconds?

Tags: datetime

I have stucked with a problem.

my code in Controller is:

```
'Date-' + system.now() + ':' + 'Time out-' + responseTime;
```

and I am getting response : **Date-2013-11-19 10:19:33:Time out-3600**

responseTime = 3600 (which is in seconds)

Here I want to add Date with Time out so that the response should come in this format: **Date-2013-11-19 10:29:33**

Above we have added 3600 seconds to  2013-11-19 10:19:33 and we are getting 2013-11-19 10:29:33

Any help??

Answer (score 4):

You can add seconds to a DateTime in the following way:

```
DateTime dt = System.now(); // DateTime.now();  will also work here too
DateTime adjustedDt = dt.addSeconds(responseTime);
```

Also, 3600 seconds is an hour: **10:19:33** plus 3600 seconds is **11:19:33** not **10:29:33** as you mention above.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
dateTime dt=System.now().addSeconds(60);
```